# How to put Array Results into a foreach collection?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-core

I have the following code which collects fiels from various directories:

```
    $Working_Dir1 = "$Env:ARCHIVEPATH\FDMEE\Data-$Env:_ENV\Actuals\Full_Year"
    $Latest_Dir = Get-ChildItem "$Working_Dir1" | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    $Working_Dir1 = Get-ChildItem "$Working_Dir1\$Latest_Dir\" | Where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_.FullName}
    
    $Working_Dir2 = "$Env:ARCHIVEPATH\FDMEE\Data-$Env:_ENV\Actuals\Rolling"
    $Latest_Dir2 = Get-ChildItem "$Working_Dir2" | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    $Working_Dir2 = Get-ChildItem "$Working_Dir2\$Latest_Dir2\" | Where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_.FullName}
    
    $Working_Dir3 = Get-ChildItem "$Env:FILE_BIN" | Where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_.FullName}
```

I want to then iterate on all of those files in order to read their contents.  However, I"m having trouble storing them into a variable and using it into a collection.

```
$Dirs = "$Working_Dir1","$Working_Dir2","$Working_Dir3"

$EntitySiteList = @()
try {
    $EntitySiteList = foreach($Name in $Dirs){
        Write-Host "$Name"
        Write-Host "will do other stuff here once I figure this out"
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Encountered the following error : $($Error[0])"
    exit 1
}
```

It's only reading the results of Working_Dir1 and nothing else for some reason. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: `Write-Host` writes to the information stream.

Comment: Add some logging and verify that your 3 variables contain what you expect - e.g. ```write-host “working dir 1 = $($Working_Dir1 | fl | out-string)”``` and the same for working dir 2 & 3. Your line ```$dirs = …``` is also a bit strange - you’re potentially stringifying multiple files into a single string value for each working directory - at most your ```foreach``` loop will only iterate *3* times (once for each variable, *not* once for each file in the working directories)…

Comment: Abraham - yes, I'll change to Write-Output. 

mclayton, yes, all "Working_Dir*" variables contains my expected results.

Comment: If I put "$Dirs = $Working_Dir1 + $Working_Dir2 + $Working_Dir3" in the Console and then "foreach ($name in $Dirs){Write-Output $Name}" it returns as I would expect. But why would it be behaving differently in the script?

Comment: try this instead:

`$Dirs = @() ; $Dirs += "$Working_Dir1" ; $Dirs += "$Working_Dir2" ; $Dirs += "$Working_Dir3"`

Comment: KG - thanks, but that didn't work. When I then use "foreach($Name in $Dirs){Write-Output $Name }" the output is just a very long SINGLE line with all values separated by a space

Comment: Use the PowerShell [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines), e.g.: `$EntitySiteList = $Working_Dir1, $Working_Dir2, $Working_Dir3 | Foreach-Object { $_.Name }`

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you to leave the custom error handling (`Try`/`Catch`) if you just "*try to figure*" things, the native PowerShell error handeling is simply  more straight and less confusing.

Comment: @chrtak - the *unquoted* version appends all the items in each array into a new array and the foreach processes them one at a time - e.g. ```$a = @(1, 2, 3); $b = @(4, 5, 6); $c = @(7, 8, 9); $x = $a + $b + $c; foreach( $I in $x ) { write-host $i }```  ~ each item will be shown on its own line here, whereas in the quoted version each array is first converted into a single string and then *those* are appended into a new *string* - ```$x = “$a” + “$b” + “$c”```. The output from the foreach here would be the single line: ```1 2 34 5 67 8 9```.